# NHibernate: Instance failure during BuildSessionFactory

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying NHibernate and at the beginning I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
>   ...
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
>   ...
>   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
>   at NHibernateDemo.Program.Main(String[] args)

The configuration is:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns = "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
  <property name = "connection.connection_string">
    Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NHibernateDemoDB;Integrated Security=SSPI
  </property>

  <property name = "connection.driver_class">
    NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
  </property>

  <property name = "dialect">
    NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect
  </property>

  <mapping assembly = "NHibernateDemo"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The code is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();

        var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

How can I solve it?

Maybe there is a problem in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the double quotes in the connection string: change it to this.

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; …
```

Ref: [Fixing "Instance Failure" when connecting to Sql Server](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixingInstanceFailureWhenConnectingToSQLServer2005Express.aspx)